# Link to external page has wordpress blog-url inside

Tags: php, functions, redirect, links

I am modifying a theme.

The initial function looked like that

```
function tmnf_ratingbar() {
    $rinter = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tmnf_rating_main', true);
    if ($rinter > 0) {
        return  '<span class="ratingbar">
                <span class="overrating" style="width:'.$rinter .'%"></span>
                <span class="overratingnr">'. $rinter .'<br/><span>&#37;</span></span>
            </span>';
        }
}
```

However, I would like to insert a link where the rating is outputted. Hence, I changed the function like that::

```
function tmnf_ratingbar() {
    $rinter = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tmnf_rating_main', true);
    return  '<span class="ratingbar">
                <span class="overrating" style="width:'.$rinter .'%"></span>
                <a href='. $rinter  .'> Check it out!</a>
            </span>';

}
```

My problem is that even though the, `check it out` is now a link, the link does not work in the browser, because it links to:

```
http://example.org/www.google.com
```

Which gives me the `Nothing found page` of my theme.

Any suggestion, how to change the `$rinter` object to only link to f.ex.: `google.com`, instead of `http://example.org/www.google.com`?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using `$rinter` as a number and at the same time as an URL for the anchor element.

Secondly, the `href` attribute requires mentioning the protocol (`http(s)://` for example) in front of the domain or else it will just be relative to the current viewing address. (`$rinter` should be something like `http://www.w3.org` instead of just `www.w3.org`)